# Creating multi-layered SVG waves in CSS

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to create a wave effect on a website [like this](https://dribbble.com/shots/5115653-Augmented-reality-web-concept-work/attachments) where there is a main color wave (dark purple) and then lighter colored waves along the edge. I have tried positioning multiple paths with CSS position and top but cannot get them to work.

Here's my basic wave:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
    <path class="green" fill="#0b5b41" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,224L60,213.3C120,203,240,181,360,186.7C480,192,600,224,720,245.3C840,267,960,277,1080,250.7C1200,224,1320,160,1380,128L1440,96L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Use Inkscape or Illustrator, draw your artwork, export it and use it. I'm sure there is online vector software.BTW inskape is free

Answer (score 3):

Mybe so

Three separate waves. The color of each wave can be selected to your liking.

The app is responsive and looks the same in all modern browsers

```css
.w1 {
fill:#0E7452;
opacity:0.4;
}
.w2 {
fill:#0E7452;
opacity:0.7;
}
.w3 {
fill:#0B5B41;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1440 320" version="1.1">
  <path class="w1"  d="m-1.2 155.9c0 0 45.8-1.8 68.7-0.8 96.9 4.3 213.1 15.7 289.6 28.9 120 19 241.7 41.5 361.7 62.8 120 21.7 269.8 29.2 389.8 2.9C1228.6 222.9 1320 108 1380 76l60-32v224l-60 52-293-1.1H734L363.5 317.2 75.8 322.4 0 268c0 0-1.2-81.2-1.2-112.1z"/>
  
  <path class="w2"   d="m-1.2 186.8c0 0 45-1.1 67.5-2 190.8-7.9 184.4-4 297.5 2 120 5.3 241.2 42.3 361.2 63.6 120 21.7 245 23 365-3.3 120-26.7 194-95.4 290.1-145.1 20.1-10.4 60-32 60-32V294H1380 1080 720 360 60 0Z" />

  <path class="w3" d="M0 224 60 213.3C120 203 228.9 182.5 348.9 188.2 468.9 193.5 600 224 720 245.3 840 267 960 277 1080 250.7 1200 224 1320 160 1380 128l60-32V320H1380 1080 720 360 60 0Z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: It's how should be done. Just an observation: you can simplify a lot the d attribute. For the same curve I would have used  `d="M0,224
C120,203,240,181,360,186.7                                             C480,192,600,224,720,245.3
C840,267,960,277,1080,250.7
C1200,224,1320,160,1440,96
V320H0Z"`

Comment: @enxaneta I thought it’s easier for the OP to have three paths so that each one can be painted in different colors

Comment: @Ping If the answer was useful to you, please do not forget to mark it.