# How to generate a SVG wave in HTML

Tags: svg

I am quite new with SVG in HTML. I want to make an SVG like the wave you see in the picture (please ignore the background image that's a different DIV element). I tried various SVG generators but didn't get the exact thing. If someone can please help me out with this.

This is the SVG I want:

[image: SVG I want]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please give what you have tried, because that will help us help you better.

Comment: Also, if you can, try using a [png-to-svg converter](https://convertio.co/png-svg/) if you have a PNG of it or can obtain one (that looks like some PNG from another site you may be able to take).  Or you can simply inspect and copy the code they used (be careful of licensing).

Comment: please take a look at this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59329091/creating-multi-layered-svg-waves-in-css#59330291